# How to redirect to localhost home on entering any non existing url?

Tags: redirect, domain-name-system, lighttpd, hijack

I am working on an intranet application running over
Lighttpd server, it is hosted on 192.168.0.1 and
there is nothing else on server.

I want to redirect any page request made to server
(e.g.: "xyz.com") redirect on 192.168.0.1.  I am working
on python django framework.

Is it possible by making some changes in lighttpd.conf file, or by changing DNS (I am using dnsmask) or even by mod_rewrite?
I am totally helpless.

Comment: do you mean you have domains suchas xyz.com with local DNS setup pointing to your server and you want to redirect all domains that you are not explitcitly handling in your lighttpd config to some default site?

Answer (score 0):

Put the following line in your /etc/hosts:

```
192.168.0.1 xyz.com
```

Comment: i want to redirect user on 192.168.0.1 on any url user enters on browser...is it possible??